# Volume of revolution of $y=\sqrt {x+2},y=x,y=0$ about $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

**Q**: Volume of revolution of $y=\sqrt {x+2},y=x,y=0$ about $x$-axis using **the shell method**.
**My Approach**: I know how to use shell method. For shell method height and radius are the main thing, because $V=2\pi\int R(y)H(y)dy$ 
 That's why I found height $$H(y)=y-(y^2-2).$$ But I cannot write $R(y)$, because for $x\in[-2,0]$ the lower curve is $y=0$ and for $x\in[0,2]$ the lower curve is $y=x$. Then how could i find the volume using **shell** method. Any hints or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.[image: the question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axis of rotation is the x axis.

Since you are using the *shells method*, then the shells shall be the *horizontal* hollow cylinders made by the 
rotation of the rectangles having a side on the line at constant $y$, and height $dy$  . The lenght of the horizontal side is 
$\Delta x = x_2(y)-x_1(y)=y-(y^2-2)$.
Now, $\Delta x$ remains non-negative on the range $0 \le y \le 2$, which is the range over which you shall integrate.
The segment $(-2,0),(0,0)$ is horizontal, and does not represent an obstacle using this method.

[image: Parab_Cono_1]

So the volume is
$$
\eqalign{
  & V = 2\pi \int_0^2 {y\left( {y - \left( {y^{\,2}  - 2} \right)} \right)dy}  =   \cr 
  &  = 2\pi \int_0^2 {\left( { - y^{\,3}  + y^{\,2}  + 2y} \right)dy}  = 2\pi \left( { - {{16} \over 4} + {8 \over 3} + 2{4 \over 2}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{16} \over 3}\pi  \cr} 
$$
which is the answer you are given.

You can countercheck this by performing the integration by "disks", i.e. vertical circular cross-sections.
These are solid cylinders, with a circulat basis centered at $(x,0)$, having radius $y(x)$, and thickness of $dx$.
In this method, the discontinuity between the line $y=0$ and $y=x$ requires some attention.
We just have to split the integral into two parts :
$$
\eqalign{
  & V = \int_{x =  - 2}^0 {\pi y_{\,1} (x)^{\,2} dx}  + \int_{x = 0}^2 {\left( {\pi y_{\,1} (x)^{\,2}  - \pi y_{\,2} (x)^{\,2} } \right)dx}  =   \cr 
  &  = \pi \left( {\int_{x =  - 2}^0 {\left( {x + 2} \right)dx}  + \int_{x = 0}^2 {\left( {x + 2 - x^{\,2} } \right)dx} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \pi \left( {{4 \over 2} + \left( {2 \cdot 2 + {4 \over 2} - {8 \over 3}} \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{16} \over 3}\pi  \cr} 
$$

Comment: Did you mean the total volume is $=(y \cdot (2-(y^2-2))\cdot dy | y=0..2)-(y \cdot (2-y)\cdot dy | y=0..2)$ and can you explain what does " $y$ is going from $0$ with $\Delta x = 2$ " mean please ? And thanks  @G Cab

Comment: @mdemon The axis of rotation is the x axis. The shells you are taking are the horizontal hollow cylinders made by the rotation of the rectangles having a side on the line at constant $y$, height $dy$. The lenght of the horizontal side is $\Delta x=x_{right}(y)-x_{left}(y)=y-(y^2-2)$. The lenght is non-negative for $0 \le y \le 2$, and that is the range over which you have to integrate.

Comment: Thanks a lot @G Cab .but after doing the integration it gives me $2.667$ but the actual answer given by the book is $\frac{16\pi}{3} .$ Is the answer is wrong or i failed to do the integration.

Comment: @mdemon: I recasted my reply, trying to make it more clear. Let me know if you have still something unclear.

Comment: Now i got it @G Cab

Comment: @mdemon: good, glad it helped.